# How to route 2 different URL's to the same action in Rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm dealing with an application that's using Rails 2.3.18 and I'm wondering if it's possible to route multiple url's to the same action without creating a new map.

```
map.home '/', :controller => 'pages', :action=>'home', :path=>'home'
```

Is it possible to route to '/', as well as '/home' in this mapping?

I've been having a look through the routing documentation and I can't seem to find anything that allows you to do something like this, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
map.home '/', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'home'
map.home '/home', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'home'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do these routes as :

```
root "page#home" // this work as root for '/' path
```

&

```
get "/home" => "page#home"
```

This is the solution but if you want to do it with seperate routes without root_path then :

```
get "/" => "page#home" 
get "/home" => "page#home"
```